# Select rows by criteria to fill a list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, where-clause

I have a List `Users` and I want to select those rows which have `Username` to fill the `Users` list.

For example, `Users` list contains "joe" and "marry". I want select rows which have `Username` field as "joe" or "marry". How do I write this?

```
List<string> Users = new List<string>() {"joe", "marry"};
model = model.Where(r => r.UserName ???
```

Comment: similar tsql would be where r.username in ( 'joe', 'marry' )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
model = model.Where(r => Users.Contains(r.Username));
```

Comment: Make sure that the List is a List or an Array of a primitive (like string) or alternatively an IQueryable from the same context. Else Linq will try sending complex classes down to Entity Framework (the database) and EF-Linq will complain, that SQL does not support `Enumerable.Where'string` or  `List'Foo`

Comment: thanks. it worked. and Users comes from Roles.GetUsersInRole(role);